# Inserting linked list in C++

Tags: c++, structure

I need to insert 0 between two negative values in linked list. But my function doesn't work. What's wrong?

P. S. listLength passes information about length of linked list.

Insert function:

```
void insert(int new_value, int preceed_num)
{
    struct List1* last;
    struct List1 *brand_new;
    brand_new = new(struct List1);
    last = getAddress(preceed_num - 1);
    brand_new -> Next = last -> Next;
    last -> Next = brand_new;   
    brand_new -> Info = new_value;
    amount++;
}
```

Inserting zero between two values function:

```
void insert_zero_unction()
{
    int length = listLength();
    int first, second;
    for(int count = 1; count < length; count++)
    {
        first = getValue(count);
        second = getValue(count + 1);
        if(first < 0 && second < 0)
        {
            insert(0, first);
            length++;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `amount++` increases amount of elements in the list, the same as `length++`

Comment: Traversing the list to find its length, and then traversing twice for each two consecutive values is very inefficient. You can do this during one traversal.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use indexes to iterate through linked list. It can be deadly slow. Consider the use of `getValue` in `insert_zero_unction`. Unless you have some sort of caching scheme going on behind the scenes, you find the node at `count` and then you redo all of that work finding the node at `count+1` when you could have simply used the `next` pointer. If you run into performance problems later start by taking advantage of the nodes.

Comment: it is working a bit slow, actually. okay, will deal with it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as @molbdnilo and @user4581301 said, traversing the list and using pointers in algorithm solved the problem. Here is re-written code:

```
void Zeroed_Stack_Function()
{
    int length = listLength();
    struct List1* first, *second;
    int count = 1;
    int to_past;
    while(count <= length)
    {
        first = getAddress(count - 1);
        second = getAddress(count);
        if(first -> Info < 0 && second -> Info < 0)
        {
            insert(0, count);
        }
        length = listLength(); 
        count++;
    }
}
```